# Реализация открытия стартового Activity

Tags: java, android

Есть логин activity - а, после логгирования юзер попадает в Activity -b, при сворачивании приложения и открытии ,снова открыватеся activity -a, но каждый раз вводить юзеру свои даные, логироваться -напряжно.

Как реализуются старты приложений когда нужные ранне формы отпадают, и нужно стартовать с activity-b?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно сохранять статус авторизации, в самом простом случае, в виде флага в `SharedPreferences`.

После авторизации сохраняете статус:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("IS_AUTHORIZED", true);
editor.commit();
```

После разлогинивания:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("IS_AUTHORIZED", false);
editor.commit();
```

При запуске активити получаете статус:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isAuthodized = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("IS_AUTHORIZED", false);
```

Если `isAuthodized == true`, то открываете нужную активити.

Также, активити с авторизацией целесообразно указать атрибут `android:noHistory="true"`.